# Missing extension "moregreetings" after upgrade to CiviCRM 5.36

Tags: extension

I am running CiviCRM with the extension Moregreetings.

After upgrading CiviCRM to version 5.36 without other problems, I got two notifications:

> Unknown extension: de.systopia.moregreetings
> Warning: Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module.

I am wondering how I have to solve this issue. I would like to know if it is safe just to reinstall the extension. I fear to loose the huge work for setting up this extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing when you upgraded you somehow deleted your extensions folder. All you need to do is put the code files for the moregreetings extension back into that folder.

Comment: Thank you. Probably, I installed the extension the first time in a wrong directory (but it worked until the update!). Now I extracted the files in `$DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext`. I still had to disable and to enable the extension in order to make it work. If the installation instructions of the extension `moregreetings` were clearer, this wouldn't have happened.